# Insert without duplicates mysql without unique key

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a program that is reading a credit card statement and I need it to insert it into a table. The problem i am having is when i just use insert it will let the user insert the same information over and over again. However I really cant set any of the columns as unique because there can be duplicates in all of the fields.
The fields i have are DATE | Description | Amount
So the user could have used the card on the same date at the same place and for the same amount. These are monthly statements so is there a way to do this besides insert ignore while using a unique key??
Brent

Comment: Is it possible to add 2 records w/ all equal fields?

Comment: If there is no information that is logically unique, there is no way to tell that a record is a duplicate. Real CC processing systems add transaction IDs to the list, which uniquely identify a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify the business rules: Either something is required to be unique (a single column or a combination of columns) or identical lines are allowed.

If identical lines are valid, i.e. the user have used the card twice on the same date, at the same place for the same amount you cannot require the data to be unique.

What you can do is to add a warning to the user (if the data entry is interactive) if there is already an existing identical line. If you are doing some batch import you could issue a warning if all (or at least a contigous block) of transactions are identical to already existing ones.